# How can I reassign the result of a listener function that is executed repeatedly?

Tags: node.js, typescript, listener

I have a function which consumes a Queue from RabbitMQ and I want to save the result of every time it's executed to run some other code (e.g. save something in database).

The problem here is that it's only saved once, the listener keeps working fine and getting that information as the code within the function keeps being executed as I add more events to the queue but without reassigning the result of the execution to that variable:

Here's my code:

*Controller (which calls the consumer)*

```
async run() {
    const eventData = await this.eventManager.consume(QueuesToConsume.USER_CREATED)
    await this.createUserUseCase.run(eventData);
}
```

*RabbitMQ consumer*

```
async consume(queue: string): Promise<DomainEvent> {
  let eventData: DomainEvent;

  return new Promise<DomainEvent>(async (resolve, reject) => {
    await this.channel.consume(queue, async (msg: Message) => {
      console.log(`Message: \n ${Buffer.from(msg.content)} \n received successfully!`)

      await this.channel.ack(msg)
      eventData = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(msg.content).toString('utf8'))
      console.log('Message acknowledged successfully')

      resolve(eventData);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(`Error consuming the message: \n ${err}`)
      reject(err)
    });
  })
}
```

So this is not working properly as eventData in the controller doesn't get every response and the useCase can only be executed the first time.

How can I fix this for eventData to get every result the consumer es returning?

*PS: Note that I didn't copied the whole piece of code because it is not necessary, I can happily copy it if you need it to give me a proper answer!*

Comment: Promise can't resolve more than once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found some other stack overflow forums that discussed this and in summary this can not be done, whether it is done with promises or with traditional async await, a variable can't just be reassigned to a value every time the listener listens to something.

I have found a workaround that allows me to achieve what I wanted at the very beginning using the Observer/Subject design pattern in which the RabbitMQ consumer that will be the subject will also notify the observers with the new event.

This way also helps a lot if you want that event to trigger two actions or usecases rather than one, you just have to add the new action as an observer and you're good to go!